# Jquery KeyPress Doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea why this doesn't work whatsoever on any browser?

If i try it in jsfiddle it works.

```
$('#input_area').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="counts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="input_area"/>

</body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#input_area').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Can you link us to the fiddle you used?

Comment: any error message? sample html? Are you binding the keypress on `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/Mpcpd/

Comment: It works here in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/XRER3/ If you got it to work in jsfiddle.net then it must be working in SOME browser.  Where exactly is this not working?

Comment: If it works in an isolated case on jsfiddle, the problem is surely with the markup or code context. We can't help you unless you post more code.

Comment: Please post another link to the same fiddle. 4 (so far) is not enough.

Comment: EDITED the original post to add code.

Answer (score 4):

I am ready to bet 5 bucks that you didn't wrap it in a `document.ready` handler in your actual application which jsfiddle does by default:

```
$(function() {
    $('#input_area').keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
        }
    });
});
```

Another possibility is you forgot to reference jQuery or you referenced it from a wrong url.

Comment: It just does not want to work. Everything is correctly implemented both the ready and source links.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser, the `which` property might not be implemented.  You should also check for `keyCode`:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#input_area").keypress(function (e) {
       if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
         alert('You pressed enter!');
       }
    });
 });
```

Comment: jQuery takes care of those cross-browser issues. `e.which` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it works when running in jsfiddle, then it works. I suspect you're trying to register the keypress listener when the dom is not loaded yet, and input_area is not available yet. Wrap it inside $(document).ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input_area').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            alert('You pressed enter!');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use binding,

```
$('#input_area').bind('keypress', function(e){
    alert(e.which);
});
```